# Reading TIFF image from file using BufferedImage and JAI

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio, jai

I'm trying to read a TIFF image from file using BufferedImage. The following is my code:

```
String filename = "/image/parrot.tiff";
File f = new File (filename);
try{
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
}catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
}
```

But it isn't working. I have a method called testInput just to test if the file was read properly:

```
public void testInput(){
    System.out.println(f.exists());
    System.out.println(f.canRead());
    System.out.println(f.canWrite());
}*/
```

The three of them would always return "false" and the above code always returns "Something went wrong!". I already added JAI ImageIO for the plug-in to read TIFF image. Any idea what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem silly, but are you sure your file is placed in

```
/image/parrot.tiff
```

?

According to the Javadoc, exists() returns :

> true if and only if the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists; false otherwise

So I think the path may be wrong. According to your comment, I think the correct path should be

```
src/image/parrot.tiff
```

If it isn't, try

```
src/image/parrot.tiff
```

In all cases, you must understand better how file path are managed in Java (and in most other languages) ;-)

Comment: My source files are all in a folder named 'src' and inside 'src' there's a folder named 'image' where I put the parrot.tiff. I also tried putting parrot.tiff to the src folder and change filename to "parrot.tiff" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, so I'm right. You have a leading slash in your path, and you shouldn't. I edit my answer.

Comment: I changed it to: src/image/fig38a.tif and it works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that you actually have JAI at the ready.  JAI is a plug-in extension to ImageIO and if it's not there then you can't decode TIFFs. Here's a quick unit test:

```
@Test
public void canGetTiffDecoder()
{
    Iterator<ImageReader> reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("TIFF");
    assertNotNull(reader);
    assertTrue("No tiff decoder", reader.hasNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It also matters what format of tif is used.  Even with the JAI plug-in, only some forms of tiff are supported.  For instance, when I downloaded a bluemarble.tif image, deep in the inner workings I got:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Planar (band-sequential) format TIFF is not supported.

So certain tif file formats are not supported without the help of specialized libraries.  One of those libraries is GDAL.  http://gdal.org/java/  However many of the support libraries will require native code, and may not work in a portable purely java context.